# Google Chrome using gargantuan amounts of CPU on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, performance

So, very recently, I've been having a serious problem with Google Chrome on Windows 10, it worked fine before the recent Windows 10 updates.

Recently, Google Chrome has been using gargantuan amounts of CPU recently, I noticed this in Task Manager and whenever I'm playing a game with a YouTube video in the background.

Pictures :

[image]

[image]

Why did Google Chrome suddenly use a lot of CPU? Is it because of the updates? As of right now, Chrome and Windows 10 are my favorites and I would not want to use something different.

Comment: It might depend on what is open in those windows. Many websites continuously load and process new video advertisements (even if they are not currently visible on screen). Does it happen when you have nothing open? Or after you interrupt loading on those pages?

Comment: Streaming video is quite an intensive process, especially now that YouTube has discarded Flash Player for HTML5. It does seem like a gargantuan amount of memory usage though (nice use of gargantuan, too).

Comment: Have you tried disabling any add ins/ extensions? Does this minimise the peak in CPU usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Chrome's Task Manager, hidden under Tools, and you can see which windows are slowing you down.  To verify, you can use that to shut down the worst websites you are visiting.

Since Facebook is popular, I've noticed that some of my users at work, even when I know they were not actively looking at the Facebook page, have consumed over 1 GB of bandwidth in a few hours alone.

Automatically loading and auto-playing video is a huge problem, and Chrome plugins that can force play, only on-demand with a click, is about the only way to stop this madness.  Any recommendations for the best plugins??

Comment: Thank you! It seems that YouTube was the culprut. I have resolved this issue by putting the video in 144p, i dont need 1080p60fps video just for background.