# Google Drive using huge amounts of CPU

Tags: cpu-usage, google-drive

I have a similar issue to the ones discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/804205/why-is-google-drive-so-heavy-on-my-cpu) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1114126/google-chrome-using-gargantuan-amounts-of-cpu-on-windows-10) , but those threads are several years old and I was hoping that there are new fixes.

I switched from Filestream to Google Drive recently. After the initial sync which took over 12 hours, it was operating normally for around a week. However, yesterday and today my laptop is almost non-functional because Google Drive is using so much CPU power.

[image]

CPU usage has been sitting between 25% and 35% for the past two days. I can barely use other programs while GD is running. It doesn't appear to be syncing anything, since the first sync took care of all that. I don't know what has changed in the last two days, but it is unusable at the moment. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it have a log file or creates events in Event Log?

Comment: Your CPU isn't that high. Your Memory is a lot more of a resourcehog.

Comment: @LPChip - A single process taking 30% of the CPU that is designed to be a background task isn't high?  I certainly consider it to be high, but it might be actively doing something, what that something is also taking a considerable amount of memory though.

Comment: @kandyman - Since Google is explicitly unclear on what the actual name of the program is, you actually are using, (Google) "Drive for desktop" correct?  I just want to confirm you are using the current product, because they have changed the name of the client more than one, and it's back to it's original name.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah sorry, I meant that if a single core is maxed out, it should not cause this much slow down. the memory usage causes the slow down.

Comment: @LPChip - I would agree the slow down is more linked to the memory than the processor usage.  I am not even sure what information to ask for, there is obviously a problem, but without a log or more detailed information into the process itself difficult to advise.

Comment: The program is just called Google Drive on my system (not Google Drive for Desktop"

Comment: where can I find the log files @golimar

Comment: @kandyman Dunno, search for any folder called Google Drive. Or at Event Viewer you may find something. Or try Process Explorer which gives more information than Windows Task Manager

Answer (score 1):

Within Google Drive settings:

> ### Real-time Presence in Microsoft Office
>
> **Unticked** : See if someone else is editing a shared Microsoft Office file

Then press done.